# Setting up a local PostgreSQL instance with windows with clojure?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, clojure

I'm trying to follow this tutuorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application . I'm running into some difficulties with the very initial steps though, of setting up a local postgresql database for testing.

The first snag was that running "postgres -D pg" in the windows shell resulted in an error of "Execution of PostgreSQL by a user with administrative permissions is not permitted". To get a round that, I tried running  pg_ctl start -D .\ .I think it worked, except that it couldn't access the "postgresql.conf" file.

Running "creatdb shouter" didn't work either, so I ran "createdb -U postgres shouter". But now when I try to launch lein repl, I just get this error:

```
$lein repl
Could not find artifact postgresql:postgresql:pom:8.4-702.qdbc4 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Could not find artifact postgresql:postgresql:pom:8.4-702.qdbc4 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Could not find artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.4-702.qdbc4 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
Could not find artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.4-702.qdbc4 in clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/)
Check :dependencies and :repositories for typos.
It's possible the specified jar is not in any repository.
If so, see "Free-floating Jars" under http://j.mp/repeatability
Exception in thread "Thread-1" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Could not resolve dependencies {:exit-code 1}
        at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4227)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$get_dependencies.doInvoke(classpath.clj:128)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:605)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$resolve_dependencies.doInvoke(classpath.clj:144)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at leiningen.core.eval$prep.invoke(eval.clj:60)
        at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:220)
        at leiningen.repl$start_server.doInvoke(repl.clj:65)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:470)
        at leiningen.repl$repl$fn__1788.invoke(repl.clj:145)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601)
        at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1771)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:605)
        at clojure.core$bound_fn_STAR_$fn__3984.doInvoke(core.clj:1793)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should really consider doing this on linux instead of windows.

Comment: Windows is fine, and at least in my opinion should be a first class development environment for Clojure (and we *should* strive to make it so) if you wan't to run the PostgreSQL instance on a linux box and stay within your comfortable Windows environment then addind a "local port forwad" to port 5432 on a linux box using PuTTY can make this more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like your project.clj file may not have the correct dependencies specified. here is short example project with working dependencies to compare with:

project.clj:

```
(defproject hello "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.2.3"]
                 [postgresql/postgresql "8.4-702.jdbc4"]])
```

which works from the repl.

```
user> (require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])
nil

user> (def pgsqldb {:subprotocol "postgresql"                                                              
                    :subname "//127.0.0.1:5432/dbname"                                                    
                    :user "postgres"                                                                       
                    :password "...."})
#'user/pgsqldb
user> (sql/with-connection pgsqldb )
nil

user> (sql/with-connection pgsqldb 
         (sql/with-query-results rs ["SELECT * 
                                      FROM information_schema.tables 
                                      WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
                                        AND table_schema = 'public' 
                                      ORDER BY table_type, table_name"] 
           (count rs)))
50
```